# What kinds of plants/organisms are the five protagonists of Botanicula?

Tags: botanicula

Are they based on real species, or are they imaginary? (Or a mix?)
[image: wut]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are:

- [a twig](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5ZV_lYQ9xb4)
- [a poppy seed head](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=GDiLNK_r0qc)
- [a bladder cherry (or Chinese lantern)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=47LXVHO7NDo)
- [a mushroom](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=BxROxLJt_bc)
- [a feather](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=GgdJ8ZhIh1U)